# SUM where other field is MAX value

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

I have a table like the one above, I want to calculate total of amount with largest log_id and group by user_id.

the results will be as below :

[image]

this is my example code but this is not work :(

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS example (
    `id` INT,
    `log_id` INT,
    `user_id` INT,
    `amount` INT
);

INSERT INTO example VALUES
    (1,1,10,4),
    (2,2,10,8),
    (3,3,10,2),
    (4,3,10,6),
    (5,1,12,9),
    (6,2,12,4),
    (7,1,13,7),
    (8,1,14,2),
    (9,2,14,6),
    (10,1,15,7),
    (11,2,15,4),
    (12,3,15,9),
    (13,3,15,6);

    select max(log_id) as log_id, user_id, amount from example group by user_id, amount
```

Any ideas?

Thanks, xmush

Comment: Are you able to write a query that returns the data set, without the aggregation? And see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: yeah i can. and i already update my question. thank you @Strawberry

Comment: That has a sum in it, which I specifically excluded in my question :-(

Comment: *this is my example code but this is not work* Of course, it is wrong synthactically.

Comment: For MySQL 5.x use subquery which gets maximal log_id per user_id, and join it to another copy of a table. In 8+ use window function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for RANK function and get data.

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
  id INT,
  logid int,
  userid int,
  amount INT
 );
 
 insert into test(id, logid, userid, amount)
 values (1, 1, 12,9),
        (2,2,12,4);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH testcte AS  (
 SELECT  *, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY userid order by logid desc) as rnk from test
  )
SELECT * FROM testcte WHERE rnk = 1;
```

| id | logid | userid | amount | rnk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 12 | 4 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6JgAWURivb6rqT7GXSyTn9/0)

Comment: @xmush Using the above? I don't believe you.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mn1us7Jk6xDdbZZ8xuf6qK/0 

check it @Strawberry

Answer (score -1):

Here's a 'traditional' (pre-8.0) approach...

Grab the rows holding the largest log_id for each user...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM example x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT user_id
            , MAX(log_id) log_id 
         FROM example 
        GROUP 
           BY user_id 
     ) y
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id
   AND y.log_id = x.log_id
```

Aggregate the resulting data set...

```
SELECT x.log_id
     , x.user_id
     , SUM(amount) total
  FROM example x
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT user_id, MAX(log_id) log_id FROM example GROUP BY user_id ) y
    ON y.user_id = x.user_id
   AND y.log_id = x.log_id
 GROUP
    BY x.log_id
     , x.user_id
 ORDER
    BY user_id;
```